# What ComposeParts analogue in .net core MEF?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mef

What analogue `ComposeParts(this CompositionContainer container, params object[] attributedParts);` in *.NET CORE MEF (Microsoft.Cmposition)*?

```
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
try
{
    container.ComposeParts(bootstrapper);
}
```

I read [blog](https://blog.softwarepotential.com/porting-to-net-standard-2-0-part-2-porting-mef-1-0-to-mef-2-0-on-net-core/) 
but didn't found its info.

Comment: Check out [this](https://dotnetthoughts.net/using-mef-in-dotnet-core/) dotnetthoughts page about using MEF in the .NET Core, it might help you out

Comment: Did you try using `SatisfyImports`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.composition.compositioncontextextensions.satisfyimports?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1